# How to use multiple pointers to an object by vector/map

Tags: c++, pointers, object, vector, stdmap

I have a question about using multiple pointers to an object.
I have a pointer in a vector and another one in a map.
The map uses the vector to index the object. Example code:

```
class Thing
{
public:
    int x = 1;
};

Thing obj_Thing;

std::vector<Thing*> v_Things;

v_Things.push_back(&obj_Thing);

std::map<int, Thing*> m_ThingMap;

m_ThingsMap[v_Things[0]->x] = v_Things[0]; // crucial part
```

is it good practice to assign pointers to each other like this?

Should the vector and/or map hold addresses instead? Or should I be using a pointer to pointer for the map?

Comment: `v_Things(0)` should probably be `v_Things[0]`? And `v_Things.push_back(&obj_Thing);` is quite dangerous, as it could easily create dangling pointers (`obj_Thing` lifetime may end earlier than that of the vector and map)

Comment: And instead of storing `Thing*` you probably want to store `std::shared_ptr<Thing>` instead, to ensure that the object does not get deallocated too early (and to indicate that it is shared between two separate "things")

Comment: Fixed typo, thanks. Should I still be using shared_ptr if not all members of v_Things will necessarily be in m_ThingsMap?

Comment: Why not have a `std::vector<Thing>` and a `std::map<int, std::vector<Thing>::iterator>`? Do you need a third object owning the `Thing`s?

Comment: The design goal is to have events that insert select elements from the vector into the map to avoid looping through the entire vector (which will be quite large). How fast would std::vector<Thing>::iterator> be? My knowledge of iterators are limited at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on what you want to do.

However, your approach can get really hairy when your project grows, and especially when others contribute to it.

To start with, this:

```
m_ThingsMap[v_Things[0]->x] = v_Things(0);
```

should be:

```
m_ThingsMap[v_Things[0]->x] = v_Things[0];
```

Moreover, storing raw pointers in a `std::vector` is possible, but needs special care, since you may end up with dangling pointers, if the object that a pointer points to gets deallocated too soon.

For that I suggest you to use [`std::weak_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/weak_ptr/), like this:

```
std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Thing>> v_Things;
```

in case you decide to stick with that approach (I mean if the pointer points to an object that is pointer-shared from another pointer).

---

If I were you, I would redesign my approach, since your code is not clean enough, let alone your logic; it takes one moment or two for someone to understand what is going on with all the pointers and shared places.

Comment: I do :p -------